# Can't run rails in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Working in development mode is working fine. However when I do rails s production command I have the following error message :

```
rails s production
Exiting
Traceback (most recent call last):
        20: from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
        19: from bin/rails:4:in `require'
        18: from /home/cabox/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/commands.rb:16:in `<top (required)>'
        17: from /home/cabox/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/command.rb:44:in `invoke'
        16: from /home/cabox/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/command/base.rb:63:in `perform'
        15: from /home/cabox/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor.rb:387:in `dispatch'
        14: from /home/cabox/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
        13: from /home/cabox/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
        12: from /home/cabox/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:130:in `perform'
        11: from /home/cabox/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:130:in `tap'
        10: from /home/cabox/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:135:in `block in perform'
         9: from /home/cabox/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:38:in `start'
         8: from /home/cabox/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:67:in `print_boot_information'
         7: from /home/cabox/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:96:in `use_puma?'
         6: from /home/cabox/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/rack-2.0.3/lib/rack/server.rb:301:in `server'
         5: from /home/cabox/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/rack-2.0.3/lib/rack/handler.rb:16:in `get'
         4: from /home/cabox/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/rack-2.0.3/lib/rack/handler.rb:74:in `try_require'
         3: from /home/cabox/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
         2: from /home/cabox/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:258:in `load_dependency'
         1: from /home/cabox/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `block in require'
/home/cabox/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require': cannot load such file -- rack/handler/production (LoadError)
```

I think this have to do with the last line of the error :

```
5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require': cannot load such file -- rack/handler/production (LoadError)
```

I tried to isntall the activesupport gem withouth any result. I'm running Ruby on Rails 5.1.4 with rvm running ruby 2.5.1. My OS is ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the correct commmand is:

```
rails server -e production
```

Or you can do this with full options:

```
rails s -e production -p [your port] -b [your ip address] -P tmp/pids/test.pid
```

Comment: It works, however when I load the page rails is stuck in rendering pages/home.html.erb. I think I'll just create another topic.